# Python CLI - Answer yes to all user questions

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am writing a `CLI` in python. On more than a few occasions I ask the user for a confirmation. For example - in case the `delete` argument is called I ask the user for a confirmation before I delete the file. However I want to add another argument like `-y (yes)` so that if `-y` is used I dont want the user to be prompted and go ahead and delete the file he specified.
I am posting the relevant code here:

```
def yes_no(userconfirmation):

    """     
    Converts string input and returns a boolean value.
    """

    stdout.write('%s [y/n] : ' % userconfirmation)
    while True:
        try:
            return strtobool( raw_input().lower() )
        except ValueError:
            stdout.write( 'Please respond with \'y\' or \'n\'.\n' )

#In the delete function:

if yes_no( 'Are you sure you want to delete {0}'.format( file_to_remove.split("/")[-1] ) ):
                        b.delete_key(file_to_remove)
```

when I call `python myprog.py -r file_to_remove.txt` If prompts `Are you sure you want to delete file_to_delete.py [y/n]` . If I press `y` file is deleted , if `n` is pressed file delete is aborted. I would want to be able to use `python myprog.py -r file_to_remove.txt -y` which not prompt the user for a `y/n` and directly delete the file. I am unsure how to carry out this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Just parse `-y` the way you are parsing `-r` and skip the `yes_no()` call depending on weather `-y` is present or not.

Comment: Per comments, you are using modules (argparse) you have not explained in the sample code. Please provide a code example indicating exactly what you have currently and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a parse action `store_true` in your argparser.

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('-y', action='store_true')
>>> parser.parse_args('-y'.split())
Namespace(y=True)
>>> parser.parse_args(''.split())
Namespace(y=False)
>>>
```

Now you can check value of `y` and decide if you need to ask user for a prompt. You should probably use something more descriptive than just `y` as an option I think. For example `--noprompt`.

```
>>> parser.add_argument('-n', '--noprompt', action='store_true')
>>> parser.parse_args(''.split())
Namespace(noprompt=False)
>>> parser.parse_args('--noprompt'.split())
Namespace(noprompt=True)
>>> parser.parse_args('-n'.split())
Namespace(noprompt=True)
```

Comment: Thanks I just looked up the `store_true` , I was trying the `type=bool` but that dint work